# Suppose $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ has $n$ derivatives and there exists $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M|x|^n.$ Then $f(0)=...=f^{(n-1)}(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ has $n$ derivatives and there exists $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M|x|^n.$ Then $f(0)=...=f^{(n-1)}(0)=0.$

Could anyone advise me how to approach this problem? Hints will suffice, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** : recurrence + Taylor-like formulas.

Comment: Don't hesitate to upvote the answer and write your own solution !